# Как выводить постоянно новые сообщения от сервера?

Tags: python, json, requests

Я отправляю запрос на сервер

```
r = requests.get("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/getmessages")
```

Получаю от него информацию и вывожу её

```
for message in r.json():
print(f">>> {message['user']}: {message['text']} ({message['timestamp']})\n")
```

Как мне выводить постоянно новые сообщения, те которые я не выводил?

Comment: Помнить последний `message['timestamp']` и выводить только те сообщения, что больше последнего запомненного `message['timestamp']`

Comment: Если у тех сообщений есть id, то лучше от него отталкиваться

Comment: @gil9red id нету, спасибо большое, если вам не сложно могли бы вы написать примерный код вашей подсказки

Comment: `if message['timestamp'] > saved_message_timestamp: print(...) saved_message_timestamp = message['timestamp']`

Comment: @CrazyElf что я должен писать вместо saved_message_timestamp?

Comment: Это название переменной. Заранее туда просто пустую строку можно записать. Или у вас скрипт не крутится в памяти, а запускается каждый раз? Если так, то нужно в файле последний таймстамп сохранять и потом оттуда читать при запуске скрипта.

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня почему то выходит ошибка 
if message['timestamp'] > i:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'